# Netplan configuration leads to low network speed

Tags: networking, netplan

With Ubuntu 18.04.
I want to configure my eth0 as `wakeonlan` thx to the following yaml file in/etc/netplan :

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.0.10/24]
      gateway4:  192.168.0.254
      match:
        macaddress: xxxxxxxxxxxx
      wakeonlan: true
```

But doing so leads to very bad network speed (as if there were 2 protocol stacks conflicting - but I cannot provide evidence at that moment).

The other side effect is that when this yaml file is present,  the icon representing the network is the following :

[image]

Whereas when there is not this yaml file, the icon is as follows :

[image]